# How to load library with a suffix

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

I need to load pre installed shared object with dlopen. Say it has name somelib.so

On some systems there is lib with several links: somelib.so, somelib.so.1, somelib.so.321.1

On other systems there only lib without links: somelib.so.321.1
How to load this library properly?

I do dlopen with name 'somelib.so' and this works only on systems where this link exists.

Is the only option to search for library full name if default link('somelib.so') doesn't exist in the system?

Comment: You could use [`glob`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) to get a list of all files matching some criteria, and then select a suitable file to load.

Comment: So why won't you always load that library using full name?

Comment: The .so only exists with the development package. And the so internal name is usually `.so.x`

Comment: @VTT cause I don't know it in advance

Comment: You need to state the system you are on. The flags used for `dlopen` on Debian/Ubuntu/Fedora/Red Hat/Solaris are different.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context: plugins, that are meant to be loaded via dlopen, usually come without version-numbers, eg `/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_something.so`.

Ordinary shared libraries usually have there versions:

```
libfoo.so.Majorversion.Minoversion
libfoo.so.Majorversion
libfoo so
```

The *Minorversion* part can be changed without notice, it means *compatible* change. If the *Majorversion* part changes, it is (can be) an in *incompatible* change. So I suggest you use the second version in dlopen, eg `libz.so.1` not `libz.so` or `libz.so.1.2.11`.

(To make it harder, both Majorversion and Minorversion can be structured, eg Major='1.1' Minor='1.a')